# transitionFromView memory issue of releasing newViewController and oldViewController

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
ViewController *vcObj = [[ViewController alloc]init];

[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:vcObj.view duration:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];

[self release];
```

I am not releasing `vcObj`, if i release this app will crash and if i dont release this i get memory leak.

What is the standard way to do views transition or swaps between views?

i am new to this memory thing plz help me .. i studied books and tutorials but this situation i am unable to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release objects, as views or view controllers, in completion function. Animation is executed in another thread. If u release in Main Thread then objects can not exist when onvoked in the other.

Comment: thanks a lot man ..... i write this code                                                    
aboutGame *aboutGameObj = [[aboutGame alloc]init];
    
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:aboutGameObj.view duration:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [aboutGameObj release];
    }];
    
    [self release]; and it worked fine but aboutGameObj is getting released both the way inside the block or outside the block but this code works i m new thats y i m having problem can u plz explain me thanks

Comment: First of all, please, be polite, You should start you class names with uppercase letters. We all do that and any other naming system is confusing.

Comment: Then, you have to release the object just once. Only in the completion: function, not in main thread.